# How to evaluate the following integral?

Tags: utility-theory, integral

I stumbled across an expression and I wonder how to evaluate this: $-\int_ {0} ^ {+\infty} {v(x)} dw^{+} (1-p(x))$ where $v(x)$ is some utility function and $w(p(x)) $ is a decision weighting function, dependent on some cumulative probability $p(x)$? Perhaps it's obvious but I am too blind to see it.
Thanks a lot for any ideas!
EDIT:Expression has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicit knowledge of the functions $v,w,p$ or some relationships between them you cannot evaluate this integral. With explicit knowledge (or relationships) you can apply the rules
$$
dw(p(x))=w'(p(x))\,p'(x)\,dx\,,\quad\quad dw(1-p(x))=-w'(1-p(x))\,p'(x)\,dx\,
$$
to see if you get something that can be integrated. I gave both formulas because your formulas involving $w$ and $p$ are ambiguous.

Comment: Hi Kurt, thank you for your answer. Actually I found the expression in this paper: "Stocks as Lotteries: The Implications of Probability Weighting for Security Prices" by Barberis and Huang, https://nicholasbarberis.github.io/pwf_final.pdf there Eq. 13 and 14..
Im not sure whether I need to integrate by parts then or simply let some Gauss-Laguerre Quadrature do the job as I can swap the boundaries. I appreciate any hints. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @T123J : Apparently, formula (13) is $-\int_0^{+\infty}v(x)\,dw^+(1-p(x))\,.$ You omitted the $+$ superscript which is a game changer (similar in formula (14)). There are many numerical integration methods to handle this. In python you can use quad. A Gauss method I would not recommend since this works well only for smooth integrands. Your's isn't smooth because of the $+$ superscript.

Comment: Hi Kurt, thank you for pointing out. Would you mind to elaborate a bit on what you mean by "game changer"? I could use quad in SciPy, sure. However, my client requires it explicitly in VBA..

Comment: That's why I am so curious about the details

Comment: Even if $w$ is smooth $w^+$ will surely be not. Hence avoid Gaussian quadrature rules.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand, the superscript in$w^{+} (\dots) $  indicates another set of parameters in contrast to $w^{-} (\dots) $. I am not sure whether in the paper above, where Eq. 13 and 14 are defined in Eq 5 to 7 and 9 in particular, qualifies it to be not smooth..

Comment: $w^+(y)=\max( w(y), 0 )$ is clearly not smooth.